# Jquery multiple div same class, drag just "this" div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a drag function (not jquery UI, I don't want Jquery UI) on a `div` with a class, but I have more `div` with the same class, How can I intercept the click on `this div`

Here my code:

```
$(function(){
    var dragging = false;
    var iX, iY;

    // how can I intercept $(this, ".marker") ??
    $(".marker").mousedown(function(e) {
        dragging = true;
        iX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
        iY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
        this.setCapture && this.setCapture();
        return false;
    });
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (dragging) {
            var e = e || window.event;
            var oX = e.clientX - iX;
            var oY = e.clientY - iY;

           // how can I find the ID related to this div ?
            $('.marker').css({"left":oX + "px", "top":oY + "px"});
            return false;
        }
    };
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        dragging = false;
//      $(".marker")[0].releaseCapture();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    })
})
```

And here the original codePen https://codepen.io/Jonh/pen/jgyLB

Here the JS that create the div, they are created by JS dynamically

```
for (i = 0; i < theFeat.length; i++) {
    markerText = theFeat[i].value;
    mk_totalHeight += 50;

$('<div>', { id: 'd' + i, style:"top:" + mk_totalHeight + "px;"}).addClass('marker').appendTo('#map');

$('<div>', { id: i, style:"background-image:url('../../../symbols/marker" + (i + 1) + ".png');" }).addClass('markerIcon').appendTo('#d'+ i);

$('<span>', { id: 's' + i, text: markerText}).appendTo('#d' + i);

} // end for loop
```

It's useful if you have just one `div` but how can I implement that on a class that is on a various `div`, I have to copy the function and add as a select the ID? (the max allowed `div` are 4, so it will be `#d0`, `#d1`, `#d2`, `#d3`)

Comment: You can use "event.currentTarget" to get the current element instead of this.

Comment: In your `$('.marker').mousedown(...)` have you tried `console.log(this);`? Inside the triggered function, jQuery gives you `this` as the context of the event itself. Or you could also look at e.currentTarget .

Comment: the problem was on  `document.onmousemove` So I add a variable to have the div and the get the `ID`
`$(".marker").mousedown(function(e) {
  dragging = true;
  mdiv = $(this);
  iX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
  iY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
  this.setCapture && this.setCapture();
  return false;
 });
 document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (dragging) {
   var e = e || window.event;
   var oX = e.clientX - iX;
   var oY = e.clientY - iY;
   $("#" + mdiv.attr('id')).css({"left":oX + "px", "top":oY + "px"});
   return false;
  }
 };`

Comment: Since you have dynamically added elements, I suggest using `.on("mousedown"....` within a `$(document).ready..` This will ensure the elements exist. Also, as previously mentioned `$(this)` should give you the current `$('.marker')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of your listeners,

```
// how can I intercept $(this, ".marker") ??
  $(".marker").mousedown(function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    iX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    iY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    this.setCapture && this.setCapture();
    return false;
  });
```

...won't, in fact, work as you expect. Because the `.marker` elements are being created dynamically, event listeners on them will fail. Rather, listen at the nearest parent node:

```
// Try something like this:
$("#map").on("mousedown", ".marker", function(e){
  // Either of the following should get to the element that 
  //  triggered the mousedown
  var target = $(this);
  // OR YOU CAN USE
  var target = $(e.currentTarget);

  // ... whatever other processing you need...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After the comment of @Snowmonkey I notice that the problem was on `document.onmousemove` where do you change the CSS property, this is my solution.

I created a `var` to get the selected `div`

```
$(".marker").mousedown(function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    mdiv = $(this);
    iX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    iY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    this.setCapture && this.setCapture();
    return false;
});
```

Then on the `onmousemove` function, I have the target stored on a `var` and I can get the `ID`

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var oX = e.clientX - iX;
        var oY = e.clientY - iY;
        $("#" + mdiv.attr('id')).css({"left":oX + "px", "top":oY + "px"});
        return false;
    }
};
```